# ORA-27100: shared memory realm already exists oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle-10g

I'm trying to start our db after performing a `shutdown abort` on a oracle 10g server, but I'm getting the following message:

> ORA-27100: shared memory realm already exists
>   Linux Error: 17: File

Oracle 10g running under Centos 6.x

Anyone know any leads about solving that issue? I found [this link](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_27100_shared_memory_realm_already_exists.htm) but since I don't have a extensive background on oracle db administration I rather confirm if I should  follow these instructions.

EDIT In 2017 : This is an old question when I was on a company that I no longer work for. Sadly I never had the change to solve this neither have the current scenario to reproduce this error.

Comment: Edit your question with the output of `ipcs -a|grep oracle` and `ps auxww| grep pmon`

Answer (score 1):

Phil is right - you need to see if you have any orphan Oracle processes and ipcs shared memory.

If you have more than one Oracle instance on your server, include the instance in your grep commands; more than likely, you may have some orphan Oracle processes still running.  Assuming your SID is `custdev`, you could do a

```
ps -fu oracle | grep custdev
```

and then do a `kill -9 PID` (where *PID* is the process ID) on any of the PIDs that show up.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to resolve this issue is by checking and remove orphaned Oracle memory segments by executing sysresv utility or by deleting all not used semaphores and shared memory of Oracle user by executing a script which you can take here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2143404/delete-all-shared-memory-and-semaphores-on-linux